# Replace Service with AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an android service to fetch data from the web that runs every fifteen minutes

```
public class SparkService extends Service {

    Handler handler;

    public SparkService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("Starting Sevice", "Starting Service Successfully.");

        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    fetchDataFromServer();
                    handler.removeMessages(120);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(120, 15 * 60 * 1000);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(120, 15 * 60 * 1000);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I have found the service to be unreliable at times and seems like it's not being called if the app is inactive for a certain period of time. I want to replace the service with an AlarmManager service instead. My app is currently in production. Can I just delete the SparkService class and add another Alarm service class without affecting existing users who update the app? Or would I have to stop this SparkService in my app update so the app can function properly?

Comment: How you implement it makes no difference. After an update, you launch the app fresh. It must be launched for anything to work -- be it this service, or the scheduled AlarmManager events.

Comment: What I mean is the Service would have been scheduled for existing users but the handler code deleted when they update the app. Will this cause an issue? I was wondering if I need to keep the service to call `stopService` in the app update.

Comment: The service is stopped or killed when you update the app. That code is no longer there, as it's replaced.

Comment: Ok great thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is your entry point. So if it's killed that means all services related to its process will also be killed, like if you kill the `svchost.exe` process in Windows all sub processes like Windows update service will be stopped too and will not be running again until you launch the update manager.

The same goes for your app: the only way that a `Service` won't be stopped by killing your app (and I'm not sure about that but it can be) is if the `Service` is created with its own process using a special tag in the `Manifest`.

I think in your case you didn't set that tag so the `Service` will be only scheduled once your app is launched after the update and in that case the `Service` will behave according to the new code.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question even if you delete the service from your update users with the old version will not be affected until they update there version with the new one

Now for using Alarm manger to trigger update from your backend as you said it's a good practice as the alarm manager have different set that you can use depending or your need below a short example how to use it

```
// Get alarm manager instance
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    // Schedule
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourCustomBroadcastReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1); // first time
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            60*5*1000,//Each five minutes
            pendingIntent
    );
```

And in your broadcast receiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
publicYourBroadcastReceiver() {}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),YourService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

}

And here for more details about alarm manager 
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: What I mean is the Service would have been scheduled for existing users but the handler code deleted when they update the app. Will this cause an issue? I was wondering if I need to keep the service to call stopService in the app update.

Comment: During an update your app instance will be killed so any service related to your app will be also stopped so no no issue will occures

Comment: However, some services automatically relaunch even after the app is killed, right?